# html5 js one page that look multipage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i'm working on a HTML5/bootstrap app that need for several reason to be a single page app.
i'm looking on a way to 'simulate' multipage on a single page
for example to hide "customer" "partner" "subscriver" section when profile section is shown
i'dont want that users can scroll down from one section to another

i really need to have a single page, so librairy like pagify doen't work and iframe doesn't work as well
any idea ?

thanks

Comment: Just handle page "changing" with javascript manpulating the visible DOM

Comment: You can use [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/), which will enable you to keep a track of which section you are in, and then just use `setAllowScrolling(false)` to disable the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse If you use Bootstrap you can hide and show div's on the fly.

Greets,
Michel

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to keep everything on one page, but only show one section at a time.  You can do this with javascript by hiding all the divs using CSS, then setting each nav button click to show the corresponding div:

```
 <input type="submit" id="custbtn" value="Customers" />
 <input type="submit" id="partbtn" value="Partners" />
 <input type="submit" id="subbtn" value="Subscribers" />

 <div id="customer">
     Customer stuff
 </div>
 <div id="partner">
     Partner stuff
 </div>
 <div id="subscriber">
     Subscriber stuff
 </div>


   $("#custbtn").click(function(){
   $("#customer").show(1000);
   $("#partner").hide(1000);
   $("#subscriber").hide(1000);
});

$("#partbtn").click(function(){
   $("#customer").hide(1000);
   $("#partner").show(1000);
   $("#subscriber").hide(1000); 
 });

 $("#subbtn").click(function(){
   $("#customer").hide(1000);
   $("#partner").hide(1000);
   $("#subscriber").show(1000);
```

});

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chasingatoms/djzusLsq/)

Comment: hi michel  i will have a try and let you know